# How to set background image of outer div only to the right of inner div?

Tags: css

I have 2 divs, one stretches over the entire screen, other is centered within.

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
#outer {
   /* This line is important */
  background: black url("https://placehold.it/1x50") repeat-x; 

  /* irrelevant */
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;  
}
```

What I want to do is set the background of the outer div, but only to the right of the inner div. Currently a 1px image is set to repeat itself over the entire outer div, but I need it to go only to the right.

When done right, background will be black on left of `inner` div and grey on right (because placehold.it image is grey).

I can change HTML if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code on your codepen

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
 <div id="inner">
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer {
 background: black; 
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

#inner {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
 }

#inner:after{
   content: "";
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1x50/fa0) repeat-x;
  top: 0px;
  right:0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(50% - 500px);
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: It needs to be an image that repeats itself to the right as long as the monitor is wide, not just 300px. Monitors to day are up to 3840px wide. I don't want to change code when they start making them even bigger.

Comment: So you have to change px to %. Ex:10%. Check it is working or not

Comment: Hey you were very close. I made it work. Do these changes and I'll accept your answer. Change `width: calc(50% - 500px);` and `background: url(http://placehold.it/1x50/fa0) repeat-x;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a linear gradient background with an abrupt color change at 50% to the body:

```
#outer {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%, #000 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 100%);
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Here's the result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWjQzm

Addition:

With a background image, you can combine a plain color background and an image. But you can't repeat the image on the x-axis, so you'd have to have an image that covers at least the background width at the right side:

```
 background: #000  url(http://placehold.it/200x50/fa0) right repeat-y;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBOgya

---

Another addition/version after comment:

You didn't yet say what kind of image that is, but if it's just a repeated 1x50px image as in you example, you might as weel stretch it to half the screen width by adding background-size: 50% 100%; - see codepen linked below:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpJKKO

Comment: I need only the bg image and it must be 1px wide, 50px high. Gradients are not acceptable.

Comment: please note the addition to my answer

Comment: This is what I see: https://snag.gy/uCW3YL.jpg     There should be no black bar between grey and yellow image. Yellow image must be 1px wide so it can be repeated until the end of monitor. Monitors today are 3840px wide and I don't want to change code or create new image when they start making them bigger which could be in 2 months from now.

Comment: You didn't yet say what kind of image that is, but if it's just a repeated 1x50px image as in you example, you might as weel stretch it by adding `background-size: 50% 100%;` for codepen see addition to my answer coming in one minute