# Why is width in percentages of ::after element not calculated according to parents div?

Tags: css

I am trying to implement this question: [How to set background image of outer div only to the right of inner div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439554/how-to-set-background-image-of-outer-div-only-to-the-right-of-inner-div)

It is presented in this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpNVmJ

What I want is that yellow image to repeat itself. It is working perfectly in that codepen, but when I try to implement it in my real code it doesn't work.

In reality image is not solid color but stripes matching the header. Gradient based solutions do not work for this.

This is my real html:

```
  <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
    <div class="inner-wrap">

      <header>
        <div class="top-row">
          <a href="/index.html" class="clickable-area"></a>
          <div class="top-ad">
          <script>
          </script>
          </div>
        </div>
       ...
       </header>
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

This is relevant scss:

```
  .top-row {
     position: relative;
     @media #{$large-up} {
       height: 110px;
     }
   }

.top-row::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: url("../images/above-menu-graphic-215-1px.png") repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right:0px;
  height: 110px;
  width: calc(50% - #{$row-width/2});
}
```

Getting a codepen working is impossible or just too much work because I need foundation 5 scss.

Inspecting in chromium shows that ::after element has width of 0.
When I change width to be just `calc(50%)` or just `50%` it shows `600px`.
Width of div `top-row` is limited to 1200px, but header is whatever is size of browser.

Width should be 50% of `header`, not of `top-row`.

To be more precise it should be `calc(50% - $row-width/2)` and $row-width/2 is calculated correctly as 600px (actually rems), so that's not a problem.

Why does width of this ::after element gets set as if it's parent is `<div class="top-row">` and not `<header>`?

How to make it work?

Comment: Is the correct operator precedence being followed in that browser? If it isn't `50% - $row-width/2` would come out as `0`. (As in: `(600px - 600px) / 2`.)

Comment: On the codepen, the parent is 1000px, and you are telling the pseudo element to be `50% - 500px` which is 500 - 500 = 0

Comment: @Ouroborus - chromium shows compiled result as `calc(50% - 37.5rem)`

Comment: @pol - it's working in codepen, please check out the codepen. `header` is not `1200px`, it's larger but `.top-row` is 1200px. But `.top-row` should not be parent of `.top-row::after`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment you made, "But `.top-row` should not be parent of `.top-row::after`", I suspect you're confusing what `::after` does.

[`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) is a pseudo-selector for a virtual element that comes last in the selected element's children.

In your code, the `::after` in `.top-row::after` would appear here:

```
<div class="top-row">
  <a href="/index.html" class="clickable-area"></a>
  <div class="top-ad">
  <script>
  </script>
  </div>
  ::after
</div>
```

And so the virtual `::after` element's parent is `.top-row`.

Comment: That was it, I have put it as `header::after` and it works now. I thought after is making it a sibling, that's what's intuitive for me. Thanks!